# How to get contour of metallic, shiny objects using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to find the contour of metallic, shiny objects such as the image below:

[image]

I have used Canny from OpenCV to get the contour of the image; however, the result (below) does draw a full contour of the original image. It has a big break at the bottom right.

[image]

I am kindly requesting any type of resource that could assist me in refining my contours such that it is continuous and (very closely) similar to the shape of the original image.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to apply a large [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering)
 to smooth out the image then [adaptive threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding). With the assumption that the object is that largest thing in the image, we can find contours then sort for the largest contour using contour area filtering.

Binary image

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian Blur, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (13,13), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,7)

# Morph close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find contours, sort for largest contour, draw contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
    break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi @nathancy. The code output is different from the output you provided here. What is the difference?

Comment: I'm using the input image you provided and the same exact code. I'm getting the same correct output. I'm using `python 3.7.4`, `numpy==1.14.5`, Windows 10, `opencv-python==4.2.0.32`

Answer (score 3):

In Python/OpenCV, you can achieve that by:

- Reading the input
- Convert to HSV colorspace and extract the saturation channel (since gray has no saturation and green does)
- Blur the image to mitigate noise
- Threshold
- Apply morphology close to fill interior holes in shiny object
- Find contours and filter on the largest (though there should be only one)
- Draw the contour on the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('shiny.jpg')

# convert to hsv and get saturation channel
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:,:,1]

# do a little Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(sat, (3,3), 0)


# threshold and invert to create initial mask
mask = 255 - cv2.threshold(blur, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology close to fill interior regions in mask
kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


# get outer contours from inverted mask and get the largest (presumably only one due to morphology filtering)
cntrs = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
result = img.copy()
area_thresh = 0
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_thresh:
        area = area_thresh
        big_contour = c

# draw largest contour
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], -1, (0,0,255), 2)


# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("shiny_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("shiny_outline.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold and Filtered Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

An alternate approach would be to threshold using cv2.inRange() on the green color.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible solution, implemented in C++ and using **k-means** as the main segmentation method. The idea behind this segmentation is that k-means (a clustering method) will group colors of similar value. Here, I'm setting k-means to find clusters of 2 colors: the background color and the foreground color.

Let's take a look at the code:

```
std::string imageName = "C://opencvImages/LSl42.jpg";
cv::Mat testImage =  cv::imread( imageName );
//apply Gaussian Blur to smooth out the input:
cv::GaussianBlur( testImage, testImage, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0 );
```

Your image has a noisy (high-frequency) background. You can blur it a bit to get a smoother gradient and improve segmentation. I applied **Gaussian Blur** with a standard kernel size of 3 x 3. Check out the difference between the input and the smoothed image:

[image]

Very cool. Now, I can pass this image to K-means. `imageQuantization` is a function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790588/detect-a-frame-with-squares-in-corners-with-opencv-js/59815605#59815605) that implements segmentation based on K-means. As I mentioned, it can group colors of similar value in clusters. That’s very handy! Let's cluster the colors in 2 groups: **foreground** object and **background**.

```
int segmentationClusters = 2; //total number of clusters in which the input will be segmented...
int iterations = 5; // k-means iterations
cv::Mat segmentedImage = imageQuantization( testImage, segmentationClusters, iterations );
```

The Result:

[image]

Quite nice, eh?

You can apply edge detection directly on this image, but I want to improve it using a little bit of **morphology**. I first convert the image to grayscale, apply Outsu’s thresholding and then perform a morphological Closing:

```
//compute grayscale image of the segmented output:
cv::Mat grayImage;
cv::cvtColor( segmentedImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY );

//get binary image via Otsu:
cv::Mat binImage;
cv::threshold( grayImage, binImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );

//Perform a morphological closing to lose up holes in the target blob:
cv::Mat SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3) );
cv::morphologyEx( binImage, binImage, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), 10 );
```

I use a rectangular structuring element of size 3x3 and 10 iterations of the closing operation, this is the result:

[image]

Next, detect edges using Canny's edge detector:

```
cv::Mat testEdges;
//setup lower and upper thresholds for Canny’s edge detection:
float lowerThreshold = 30;
float upperThreshold = 3 * lowerThreshold;
cv::Canny( binImage, testEdges, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold );
```

Lastly, get the blob’s contour:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

cv::findContours( testEdges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
 cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( 0,255,0 );
 cv::drawContours( resizedImage, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point() );
}
```

This is the final result I get:

[image]

Want to improve the result by expanding the contour? Try **dilating** the binary image with a few iterations before passing it to Canny’s edge detection. This is a test, dilating the image 5 times:

[image]

Comment: when you say 'dilating' does that mean the iterations on the morphologyEx method?

Comment: @jsibs Yes. The method has the argument "iterations" that indicates how many times the operation will be applied. For the last image, I set the iterations to 5.